# Flow maps without using virtual layers for displaying line matrix

Tags: qgis, point, line, spatial-join, origin-destination

I found this great flow map visualisation that I have been following: [Flowmap - No plugins](https://anitagraser.com/2019/05/04/flow-maps-in-qgis-no-plugins-needed/)

Unfortunately the dataset I am currently working with is far too heavy for the virtual layers to handle, so now I am looking for options.

I was told one approach is to generate all possible line combinations between points and then join the data layer on top of those to generate the matrix as a vector layer, which should be easier for QGIS to handle. I found some python scripts here on the stackexchange, unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for this project.

The point layer is generated from a shape layer using the centroids tool and have the following IDs:

[image: LayerIDs]

The dataset that needs to be joined onto this layer share origin and destination IDs with the zone layer, and those are respectively named OrigNTMzone and DestNTMzone. The data is a 6 digit number that is called "id" in the point layer.

The result of this is a visualisation of travel demand in Fyn, Denmark. I have made it using the flow maps tutorial, but I need an alternative to the virtual layer as there are too many data points for the machine to handle, and I need to be able to sort the data more efficiently for analysis purposes.

To sum it up, using a flow map visualisation technique without using plugins have resulted in a very heavy virtual layer that I cannot sort or style as the machine cannot process the SQL query with that amount of data points.

I need the visualisation to be more static so its possible to sort, style and extract the data. I have tried running some scripts to create a static vector line layer of all possible line combinations, but have been unsuccesful. I might be doing it entirely wrong. But it is very much a learning experience for me as I have been working primarily with mapping heatcamera data previously.

How should I approach this issue?

[image: Flowmap output]

Comment: The lines unfortunately doesn't transfer when saving as a geopackage. So there is no visualizations to style.

Comment: For larger datasets, a database with proper indexes is quite often indicated (`postgres` with `postgis` or else).

Comment: @JGH can you elaborate a bit more on that?

Comment: well, a database is made for joining tables with millions of records, so if you have a the point table with an index on the ID (it should anyways, since it is a primary key), the origin-destination table with the 2 IDs, create a view or a new table joining on IDs and creating the line should be a smooth process.

Comment: I just experienced data loss when I was joining the tables. I am not sure where my miss step in the process is, but there is defintely a miss step.